# How to understand "getting kicked inna head"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading this [post](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where), and meet the following words:

> Repeating yourself (three times) while programming is about as desirable as getting kicked inna head.

How to understand "`getting kicked inna head`" here? I guess its meaning should be something like "`make sb mad`", but can't find its definition in website.

Comment: The slurred "inna head" does not fit well into the register of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Being kicked in the head is not making anyone else mad, it means you are giving yourself a headache.

Answer (score 1):

"inna head" = "in the head", where "inna" is an imitation of English spoken by a person with poor enunciation.